# Android emulator : insert negative number?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-edittext

I suppose it must be easy but how do I insert a negative number in an `EditText`?

I am running the emulator on a Mac.

Thank you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just press '-' before you enter the number?

If that's not possible, there is probably something wrong with the inputType of the editText.
For example, `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` doesn't allow negative numbers. In that case you should add: `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"`.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answer so Yellos receives his rep.

Comment: sorry but when i first pressed to accept the answer it told i had to wait 10 minutes. maybe because i just registered to the site. great site. really quick answers.

Answer (score 7):

In resource file .axml, EditBox change type

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

to

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
yourEditText.setText("whatever");
```

Comment: sorry my quastion was not really clear. i mean when i run my app at the emulator, in the app i have an editText field. as a user i can't see how to write the minus (-) symbol so to enter negative number?

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setText(String.valueOf(-1));
```