# Android Edittext insert negative number

Tags: android, android-edittext

this is often asked like here [Android emulator : insert negative number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133937/android-emulator-insert-negative-number)

I have setup an edittext:

```
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edWminLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:text="0" />
```

when trying inserting a negative number, I press "-" and it inserts "-", but then it won't let me inserting any other digit! It works only by inserting the "-" after the complete number was inserted.

is this a BUG?

Comment: i can do this with your code.

Comment: so it must be the phone? it is Android 4.2.1

Comment: thanks for reply, but at the end it was my fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is simple: it is not a BUG it is the Programmer!

I just publish this in order to help others.

I had an InputFilter applied to the EditText ...

```
EdWMin.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(7, 2) });
```

here the fix allowing signs in front of digits

```
    public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);       
            if(!matcher.matches())
                return "";
            return null;
        }

    }
```